# how to select the json objects between given dates

Tags: json, datetime, jq

Below is the json response of an api. Need to fetch exchange rate from the json using jq(within shell script).
Below are the conditions:
    startdate should be eqaul to or greater than current date and enddate should be equal to or less than the current date for given currencyfrom and currencyto.

```
[
    {
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "startdate": "2019-01-31T00:00:00.000Z",
        "enddate": "2019-02-07T00:00:00.000Z",
        "source": "default",
        "exchangerate": "12",
        "currencyfrom": "AUD",
        "currencyto": "BRL",
        "id": "64ce2916-af8a-42b9-9fb9-def47f824ea2"
    },
    {
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "startdate": "2019-03-10T00:00:00.000Z",
        "enddate": "2019-03-30T00:00:00.000Z",
        "source": "default",
        "exchangerate": "13",
        "currencyfrom": "BRL",
        "currencyto": "GBP",
        "id": "4fd0dc10-d6b7-4298-924d-281a0d49c2e9"
    },
    {
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "startdate": "2019-03-10T00:00:00.000Z",
        "enddate": "2019-03-10T16:20:10.813Z",
        "source": "default",
        "exchangerate": "17",
        "currencyfrom": "AUD",
        "currencyto": "BRL",
        "id": "52bfe481-f4cf-4822-9566-886c4faeaf10"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring timezone considerations, you could use the following helper function as the basic building block for time comparisons:

```
def secs: sub("\\....(?<z>.)$"; .z) | fromdate;
```

With it, you could select the JSON objects within the array, while preserving the array structure, as follows:

```
now as $now
| map(select(.startdate|secs) <= $now and $now <= (.enddate|secs)) )
```

This doesn't quite match your description, but it does make sense.

Once the objects have been selected, you can extract the fields of interest in the usual way.